# Is there a way of getting logs for startup processes in /etc/init.d?

Tags: logs, startup, services

Is there a way of getting logs for startup processes in /etc/init.d?

I am running Raspbian (Debian Wheezy).

`dmesg` shows boot log, but does not go far enough.

Some time ago I added a script to start `tightvncserver` and have seen similar scripts posted by others.

This never seems to start, but I am at a loss to find out why. I would like to see if there are any errors generated.

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          tightvncserver
# Required-Start:    $local_fs
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start/stop tightvncserver
### END INIT INFO

# More details see: 
# http://www.penguintutor.com/linux/tightvnc

### Customize this entry
# Set the USER variable to the name of the user to start tightvncserver under
export USER='pi'
### End customization required

eval cd ~$USER

case "$1" in
  start)
    su $USER -c '/usr/bin/tightvncserver :1'
    echo "Starting TightVNC server for $USER "
    ;;
  stop)
    pkill Xtightvnc
    echo "Tightvncserver stopped"
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/tightvncserver {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
exit 0
```

Comment: `dmesg` only shows kernel logs. What distribution is your system running? And what init system, if your distribution gives you a choice?

Comment: For `upstart` init systems on ubuntu 14.04, check for logs under `/var/log/upstart/YourServiceName.log`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `service tightvncserver start` (as root) in the running system, it may give you some hints.  If not, your best option is using a serial console and logging its output.  If that isn't possible, [bootlogd](https://wiki.debian.org/bootlogd) may be able to help you out.  If you get nothing, maybe you forgot to activate your init script. What's the output of the

```
$ ls /etc/rc?.d/*tightvncserver
```

command?  If nothing, try (as root)

```
# update-rc.d tightvncserver defaults
```

Comment: Thanks. This showed that `su` was waiting for the password.   I have added the startup script above.

Comment: Did you run the `service` command as root? `su` should not require a password when invoked by root. On the other hand, see `man start-stop-daemon`, that helps a lot with these tasks.

Comment: I run the Pi headless, and am connected as user `pi` via ssh. The point of the original question was why the `init.d` script does not run `tightvncserver` on boot, which should be running as root.

Comment: That's exactly why you should run the above test as root.

Comment: Logged on as `root`  - `sudo su` and got no errors and `service tightvncserver start` runs OK.   Installed `bootlogd` - no mention of `tightvncserver`, and it still doesn't start on boot.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have a /var/log/boot file.

Answer (score 0):

For Fedora based linux, maybe you can check `/var/log/messages` file.